# Swift NSAttributedString: kCTForegroundColorAttributeName vs NSAttributedString.Key.foregoundColor

Tags: swift, cocoa, appkit, nstextview, core-foundation

I have a `CFMutableAttributedString` set with attributes of key `kCTForegroundColorAttributeName` and value of type `CGColor`.

```
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "foo bar")
let range = CFRange(location:0, length:6)
CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(attrString, range, kCTForegroundColorAttributeName, CGColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0))
```

I'm setting this String on NSTextStorage of NSTextView and none of the colors show.

However, for the same string doing this works -

```
// attrString is of type CFMutableAttributedString
let ret = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attrString)
ret.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: NSColor.red, range: NSMakeRange(0, 10))
```

Why are attribute using Core Foundation attribute names not working? What would be an efficient way to set the foreground color using core foundation API that would work with NSTextView.

I'm using Swift 5 and OSX 10.15.2.

Comment: There's no way to tell unless you share the code creating `CFMutableAttributedString` ...

Comment: `kCTForegroundColorAttributeName` is `"CTForegroundColor"` and `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` is `"NSColor"`. Have you tried `.foregroundColor` and `NSColor.red` in the `CFMutableAttributedString`?

Comment: No need to try it, it works, see [`CFMutableAttributedString`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cfmutableattributedstring-rqp): _See the attribute constants in NSAttributedString Application Kit Additions Reference for standard attribute names in macOS..._. `kCT` is a constant from the Core Text framework.

Comment: I updated the example with a call to `CFAttributedStringSetAttribute ` on NSMutableAttributedString that doesn't work.

Comment: Did you read my previous comment and the linked documentation? It says that you have to use `NSAttributedString` AppKit addition reference for attribute names in macOS = you have to use `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` with `CFMutableAttributedString`. `kCT` prefix is the CoreText framework constant, **NOT** the CoreFoundation framework.

Answer (score 0):

> Why are attribute using Core Foundation attribute names not working?

[`kCTForegroundColorAttributeName`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/kctforegroundcolorattributename) is NOT a Core Foundation attribute name. It's a Core Text attribute name and the actual value is `CTForegroundColor`.

[`CFMutableAttributedString`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cfmutableattributedstring-rqp) documentation clearly states:

> Attributes are identified by key/value pairs stored in `CFDictionary` objects. Keys must be `CFString` objects, while the corresponding values are `CFType` objects of an appropriate type. **See the attribute constants in `NSAttributedString` Application Kit Additions Reference for standard attribute names in macOS** and NSAttributedString UIKit Additions Reference on iOS.

You have to use AppKit framework constants here. The correct one is `NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor` (actual value is `NSColor` != `CTForegroundColor`).

[image]

```swift
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Hallo CoreFoundation!")
let range = CFRange(location: 6, length:14)
CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(attrString,
                               range,
                               NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor as CFString,
                               NSColor.red);

label.attributedStringValue = attrString
```